# Plotly subplot titles not showing correctly

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

I created Plotly subplots figure using for loop. Here is the code and link to the HTML file(download to view the file):

```
fig=make_subplots(rows=6,cols=2,subplot_titles=sorted(df['Region'].unique()))
for i,region in enumerate(sorted(df['Region'].unique()),start=1):
    data=df.query('Region==@region').sort_values(by='Population',ascending=False)
    mytrace=go.Bar(x=data['Country'],y=data['Population'],name=region)
    fig.add_trace(mytrace,row=math.ceil(i/2),col=math.ceil(i%2)+1)
    fig.update_layout(width=1500,height=2250)
```

Link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beridzeg45/IBSU/main/Strategic%20Management/plotly.html

As it can be seen titles are not applied correctly to the subplots.For example, Baltic countries subplot has title 'Asia' and Asian countries subplot has title 'Baltics'.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `add_trace()`, the way you are calculating the column... As you have `start=1`, the value for column comes as `2,1,2,1` as you loop through the for loop. Change that line to...

```
fig.add_trace(mytrace,row=math.ceil(i/2),col=math.ceil((i-1)%2)+1)
```

This should give the column numbers in the right order : `1,2,1,2`, which will allow you to get the titles in the right place